# Give FullTrust to UNC share for Visual Studio 2012 and .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, unc

Everytime I try to open a solution that is located on a UNC share I get this dialog:

[image]

I've tried using the `caspol.exe` utility that Hanselman talks about [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=c2eae5a7-1ad7-4828-b363-e6fbb4866335#commentstart), but it doesn't seem to work. At least not for a .Net 4 project runing in Visual Studio 2012. Running the .NET 4 version of caspol with the same arguments I get this message:

```
WARNING: The .NET Framework does not apply CAS policy by default. Any settings
shown or modified by CasPol will only affect applications that opt into using
CAS policy.

Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131738 for more information.
```

I followed that link but nothing seemed to make sense to me.

To give a little context about what I'm doing, I have Windows 7 running as VM (via VirtualBox) on my mac. I setup an SMB network share on my mac which I'm able to connect to successfully from my VM. However trying to load the solution keeps giving me this error. I know I can "un-check the box" and load everything but I want to know how to fully trust the location.

Comment: Can you disable this in "Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Warn user when project location is not trusted"? This setting was actually [broken](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/604282/trusting-network-shares-in-visual-studio-2010-net-4-0) in VS 2010, but it's indicated as fixed now.

Comment: @vcsjones could you please post this as an answer in order to have a valid answer to this question?

Comment: that share is still not fully trusted... how come caspol doesn't work any more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you disable this in "Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Warn user when project location is not trusted"? This setting was actually [broken](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/604282/trusting-network-shares-in-visual-studio-2010-net-4-0) in VS 2010, but it's indicated as fixed now for 2012.