# The name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I try to set color of rectangle from C# code. In other topic help me to use DataContext but can not bind class colors and key vmColors

MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="proba5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:proba5" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <vm:colors x:Key="vmColors"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">


        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vmColors}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Gray}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

colors.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace proba5
{
    public class colors
    {
        public string Gray
        {
            set { }
            get { return "#FF22262a"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Why i got 
**The name "colors" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:proba5".**

Comment: possible duplicate of [The name "XYZ" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ABC"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216662/the-name-xyz-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespaceabc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change property of colors.cs "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" and it's work!

Comment: I don't think that what's fixed it, maybe it forced a newbuild.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Visual Studio is not able to resolve names in XAML files if there are other compilation errors in the project or solution.

Try to fix all the other errors (and warnings). Then do a rebuild.