# The name "Settings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:App.Properties"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I got project, named Perfect. VS 2012 Ultimate, all updated.

I got a window with `xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:Perfect.Properties"` in the header

I keep getting error:

```
The name "Settings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Perfect.Properties".
```

**Project compiles, builds and runs fine** though. What the hell is with my visual studio?

I got another solution, from which I simply copied the code, there is no such error there.

UPD: There are other namespace troubles, like it can't find my custom Combobox item in my own namespace delcared like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Perfect.Misc"` and used `<local:VoidComboItem exchange="All available" />`. Class exists and works in runtime, but design editor is not working at all, so I have to use XAML and run app to see changes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a WPF app...

1- In most cases this happens when you have other compiler errors, is this the only error you have?

2- also try changing the target to Release and rebuild, then switch back.

3- keep VS updated

Comment: No errors, just several warnings. Project compiles, builds and runs

Comment: confused...you said you keep getting that error...? how come you can compile, build and even run?

Comment: is "Perfect" the namespace name of this project or the project you copied the code from?

Comment: Errors are on the list, when I try to use Design editor. Rebuilding the app clears the list and app runs, but when I try to use editor errors reappear. Reloading solution completely helps for some time, but eventually Design editor fails and I have to reload it again, and it is quite annoying, because solution is kinda huge already.

Comment: I could expect this in WPF but the bizarre thing is this only happens in the 'destination' project. have you copied the files and added (as existing files) to the project or added a file then 'copy/paste' the content ?

Comment: 'added a file then 'copy/paste' the content' and it is a destination preject, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your solution is on a network share (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16218145/647151).

Try mapping the network share to a drive and then open your solution from there.