# Error when update to latest Template10

Tags: c#, template10

After update to latest Template10, I am unable to edit my XAML in Visual Studio 2015.

Error that I get.

> The name "PageHeader" does not exist in the namespace "using:Template10.Controls".

I tried creating new project from latest Template10, and did not encounter such error. Both (my project and new project from latest Template10) uses "using:Template10.Controls" yet only my project have such error.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me its a bug in Visual Studio 2015. Switching to 32 bit (from 64 bit) worked for me. Other solution can be had here [The name "XYZ" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ABC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216662/the-name-xyz-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespaceabc)

Thanks.