# MahApps.Metro Errors appear after initial install

Tags: mahapps.metro

I've just installed the MahApps from GitHub

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

I'm getting errors immediately. In MainWindow.xaml the following line is underlined

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MetroDemo:MainWindowViewModel}
```

And there are several error messages, such as:

```
The name "MainWindowViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "cld-namespace:MetroDemo".

The name "ButtonsExample" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MetroDemo.ExampleViews".
```

The project does run, but I'm unable to inspect any of the design.

Has anyone experienced this and managed to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was to do with Parallels on my Mac.

[Issue found here, with resolution from Mick MacCallum.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216662/the-name-xyz-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-clr-namespaceabc)

The issue with the namespaces was due to VS using network share to access the files on my Mac file system.

I copied the entire project over to the absolute path on the virtual machine and the problem was solved.

The project now builds/runs correctly but I can also inspect the design.