# Strange 'missing an assembly reference?' error in wpf user control library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have below error in my `C# wpf user control library` :

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Error CS0234 The type or
>   `namespace name 'StylesTemplates' does not exist in the namespace
>   'MHToolkit'`(are you missing an assembly reference?)'`

i have resource dictionary in the folder,
the error will be disappear when i Exclude `StylesTemplate` Folder from the project

and i am using it in usercontrol
this my user control code :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MHToolkit.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MHToolkit"
             xmlns:ST="clr-namespace:MHToolkit.StylesTemplates"
             xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:MHToolkit.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <VM:MainViewModel x:Key="MainVM" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource MainVM}" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>


    <Grid>

    </Grid> </UserControl>
```

i am using `vs2014 and .net 4.5` .

i have no idea how to fix this error ?

any help will be appreciated

tanx in advance

image of solution explorer window below

[image]

Comment: What is inside that xaml? Including it into project is enough to cause compiler to process it.

Comment: `CardViewStyle` seems to be a resource. Resources dont have namespaces.

Comment: @lokusking, *seems* to be.. Another question would be [did you try to restart VS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22406897/1997232)?

Comment: @Sinatr yes i tried it too many times. but error still there

Comment: @Sinatr nothing . i just created that .

Comment: @lokusking oh no . the build action is 'Page'

Comment: @MH480, I was about to ask about it =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CardViewStyle.xaml as the Resource Dictionary
Check the below code

Add this to the current Usercontrol

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MHToolkit;component/StylesTemplates/CardviewStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

Otherwise you can add App.xaml file and used all apllication

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MHToolkit;component/StylesTemplates/CardviewStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```